# Django, use conditional settings module in wsgi.py

Tags: python, django

I'm using a settings module instead of a single settings file for my django project.  That means in my wsgi.py file I have something like this:

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings.prod")` 
or 
`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings.dev")`

depending upon my environment. I'd really like to be able to set a variable in a config file so that I can not have to go into this file and change it every time I push to prod.

Not a big deal you're saying?  Well it's easy to forget and then boom my app is insecure because it's on dev settings.  I would also use this config variable in other places in my app so I have one "global" flag that sets my app to production or dev settings.

Comment: why do you push your wsgi file every time?

Answer (score 4):

Well how about this approach, create three settings files:

- settings.py (master)
- settings_dev.py (override some settings for development server)
- settings_prod.py (override some settings for production server)

At the end of `settings.py` file check if `DEBUG=True` then import `settings_dev.py` else `settings_prod.py`:

settings.py:

```
----
try:
    if DEBUG:
        from settings_dev import *
    else:
        from settings_prod import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Using this approach you will only need to set:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

Now don't say that what if I forgot to change the `DEBUG` value for specific servers. Then the other solution is that have two separate repositories add `settings_prod.py` in git ignore list for development repository and add `settings_dev.py` in git ignore list for production. Always set `DEBUG=False` in `settings_prod.py` and `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` file, then at the end of `settings.py` file do this instead:

```
try:
    from settings_dev import *
except ImportError:
    try:
        from settings_prod import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Comment: cool solution:D it would be great though if i could have only one settings file with logic such as if ENV == 'prod': .use these creds. if ENV == "dev': then use these creds. how can this be set up?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an environment variable (or the machine- or user-name) to distinguish different machines. Preferably you set it on  the debug-one and never on production, so it can not be forgotten. Something along

```
if "yes" == os.environ.get("DJANGO_DEBUG_ENABLED"): 
    DEBUG = True
    # or 
    from settings_dev import *
else:
    DEBUG = False
    # or 
    from settings_prod import *
```

Alternatively you could put a file there which is not part of the repository and check for its presence / absence, or import the `DEBUG` from a `settings_local.py`.